# Проблема с биндом после евента

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня проблема с биндом текста второго `TextBox_SeriallBuffer` после ивента первого `TextBox_Scan`.
После ивента `TextBox_Scan` не остается текст в `TextBox_SeriallBuffer`

XAML TextBox_SerialBuffer :

```
<TextBox x:Name ="TextBox_SerialBuffer" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    TextAlignment="Justify"
    Margin="1,1,1,1" 
    Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"
    Padding="1"
    FontSize="13"
    FontFamily="Consolas"
    Text="{Binding Path=Text, 
    ElementName=TextBox_Scan, 
    Mode=TwoWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

XAML TextBox_Scan :

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox_Scan" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="173,165,0,0" 
    TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="302" 
    FontSize="13"
    KeyDown="TextBox_Scan_KeyDown" 
    FontFamily="Consolas"
    FontWeight="Normal"/>
```

Ивент `KeyDown="TextBox_Scan_KeyDown"`

C# :

```
   private void TextBox_Scan_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string Inputed_value = TextBox_Scan.Text;

        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter))
        {
            if (Inputed_value.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't scan anything", nameApp, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                logger.Info(nameWin + Fail + "You didn't scan anything");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Count_value++;
                logger.Info(nameWin + Pass + "Entered value : " + Count_value + "." + Inputed_value);
                TextBox_Scan.Clear();
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: А как оно должно работать, чтобы не было проблемы?

Comment: `После ивента TextBox_Scan не остается текст в TextBox_SeriallBuffer` - а должен? Вы связываете два контрола друг с другом, то есть `TextBox_Scan.Text` - это свойство и для `TextBox_SeriallBuffer`. Вы данные удаляете `TextBox_Scan.Clear();` из свойства, какое тогда поведение вы ждете?

Comment: Поведение что в 'TextBox_SeriallBuffer' отставалось контент.
Но наверное бинд это не умеет.
'TextBox_SerialBuffer.AppendText($"{Count_value + "." + Inputed_value}\n");' это мне поможет решить проблему.

Comment: Научитесь строить свой проект так, как положено. Не храните данные в контролах, они не созданы для этого! Сделайте свойство, или два. привяжитесь и делайте что вам надо.

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста , про какие свойства ты имеешь в виду ? Если не сложно , кинь пожалуйста ссылку с примером.

Comment: Почитайте про шаблон проектирования MVVM и реализацию интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Там и написано про как делать свойства для биндингов.